# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\AskQuestion::email()

Tags: laravel, request

I am trying to insert the data in database while using Laravel. I am getting the error

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method
>   App\AskQuestion::email()

While create.blade.php is my view and respones is the name of my table. The controller name is ResponesContoller and its code is given.

```
public function create()
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $categories = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('Sélectionnez la thématique'), '');

    $author_emails = User::all()->pluck('email', 'id')->prepend(trans('Choisissez votre email'), '');

    $ask_questions = AskQuestion::all();

    return view('admin.respones.create', compact('categories', 'author_emails', 'ask_questions'));
}

public function store(StoreResponeRequest $request)
{
    $respone = Respone::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('admin.respones.index')->with('success', 'Réponse enregistrée avec succès!');
}

public function edit(Respone $respone)
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_edit'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $categories = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('Sélectonnez la thématique'), '');

    $author_emails = User::all()->pluck('email', 'id')->prepend(trans('Choisissez votre email'), '');

    $ask_questions = AskQuestion::all()->pluck('text_question', 'id')->prepend(trans('Choisissez la question posée'), '');

    $respone->load('category', 'author_email', 'ask_question');

    return view('admin.respones.edit', compact('categories', 'author_emails', 'ask_questions', 'respone'));
}
```

The code of web.php is given and it works correctly, before I have checked as a test.
Please if anyone can help me!

Comment: Where is App\AskQuestion::email() getting called from? What does the App\AskQuestion class look like?

Comment: The mistake was my ResponseObserver.php where i make the function for to notify an asked question a response was given to him question.    Thank you @sa

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem i solve it.

```
public function created(Respone $model)
{
    $data = ['action' => 'Une réponse est apportée à votre question!', 'model_name' => 'Respone',
             'respone' => $model ];
    $askQuestions = \App\AskQuestion::WhereHas('respones', function($q) {
        return $q->where('objet_question', 'email', 'text_question');
    })->get();
    Notification::send($askQuestions, new ResponeEmailNotification($data));
}
```